# UIView subviews's layout update

Tags: objective-c, uikit

In the viewWillAppear delegate method, I'm setting subview's frames with rects ( location and size).

Now, There is one subview whose content will grow with user actions.
So, I need a callback in that superview controller ( The One I am talking on first sentence) , to update the layout. In this callback, I can find out how much the size increased, and then set other subviews frame rects too.

It can be done through calling  **setNeedsLayout** method on the view, but it requires **layoutSubviews** to be overridden on the UIView. Please note that it is not a delegate method, I need to have a custom view, Which I don't want to do,

Is there any delegate method for me to update the layout in the view's controller ?

UPDATE:
**This need to be support on iOS 4.2**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two `UIViewController` methods of possible relevance:

```
-viewWillLayoutSubviews
-viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

You can probably guess when they're called.

Comment: Sorry,  I would've mentioned required iOS 4.2 compatibility

Comment: Then you'll have to subclass UIView.